# RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, sunspot-rails, solr5, semaphore-ci

I am upgrading solr 5.3.1, I am getting following error when I run specs on `semaphoreci`

> RSolr::Error::Http:
>          RSolr::Error::Http - 500 Internal Server Error
>          Error:     {msg=SolrCore 'default' is not available due to init failure: Error opening new
>   searcher,trace=org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: SolrCore
>   'default' is not available due to init failure: Error
>   opening new searcher
>             at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.getCore(CoreContainer.java:974)
>             at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.init(HttpSolrCall.java:250)
>             at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:417)
>             at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:214)
>             at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:179)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)
>             at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)
>
> ```
>    URI: http://localhost:8981/solr/default/update?wt=json
>    Request Headers: {"Content-Type"=>"application/json"}
>    Request Data: "[{\"id\":\"Contact 1\",\"type\":[\"Contact\",\"ActiveRecord::Base\"],\"class_name\":\"Contact\",\"first_name_text\":\"Danial\",\"last_name_text\":\"Ullrich\"}]"
>
>    Backtrace: /home/runner/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rsolr-2.0.2/lib/rsolr/client.rb:195:in
> ```
>
> `rescue in execute'
>          /home/runner/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rsolr-2.0.2/lib/rsolr/client.rb:185:in`
>   execute'
>          /home/runner/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rsolr-2.0.2/lib/rsolr/client.rb:180:in
>   `send_and_receive'
>          /home/runner/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.7/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:16:in`
>   block in send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
>          /home/runner/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in
>   `block in instrument'
>          /home/runner/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in`
>   instrument'
>          /home/runner/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.7.1/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in
>   `instrument'
>          /home/runner/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/sunspot_rails-2.2.7/lib/sunspot/rails/solr_instrumentation.rb:15:in`
>   send_and_receive_with_as_instrumentation'
>          (eval):2:in `post'
>          /home/runner/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rsolr-2.0.2/lib/rsolr/client.rb:83:in`
>   update'
>          /home/runner/.rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/rsolr-2.0.2/lib/rsolr/client.rb:102:in
>   `add'
>        # (eval):2:in`post'
>        # ./spec/controllers/contacts_controller_spec.rb:319:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
>        # ------------------
>        # --- Caused by: ---
>        # Faraday::ClientError:
>        #   the server responded with status 500
>        #   (eval):2:in`post'

**Solr Logs**

```
1152 ERROR (coreLoadExecutor-6-thread-2) [   x:development] o.a.s.c.CoreContainer Error creating core [development]: Index locked for write for core 'development'. Solr now longer supports forceful unlocking via 'unlockOnStartup'. Please verify locks manually!
org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Index locked for write for core 'development'. Solr now longer supports forceful unlocking via 'unlockOnStartup'. Please verify locks manually!
  at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:820)
  at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:659)
  at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer.create(CoreContainer.java:723)
  at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:443)
  at org.apache.solr.core.CoreContainer$1.call(CoreContainer.java:434)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
  at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$1.run(ExecutorUtil.java:210)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.lucene.store.LockObtainFailedException: Index locked for write for core 'development'. Solr now longer supports forceful unlocking via 'unlockOnStartup'. Please verify locks manually!
  at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.initIndex(SolrCore.java:528)
  at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.<init>(SolrCore.java:761)
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`write.lock` file might be present under `solr/{environment}/data/index` directory due to unclean shutdown. Removing `write.lock` file will fix the issue.

Comment: saved my day. Thank you

Comment: @varunvlalan I have the same issue, but my file path is collectionNote/data/index/write.lock can I delete this and if I delete is it required any restart ? or any issue on prod. Because I am getting this issue on live server

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue even when `write.lock` was not present. Here's what solved it for me:

1) Delete entire /solr directory

2) run `ps -ef|grep solr` to see any solr processes running

3) run `kill -9 [solr pid]` for each of the processes found in step 2

4) run `rake sunspot:solr:start` and then `rake sunspot:solr:reindex`

Hope this helps!